# Actualizar estado de url dentro de una promesa axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, useeffect

estoy tratando de hacer una API de películas y he puesto unas flechas de paginación para avanzar o retrasar las página. El problema que tengo es que la URL esta en una promesa axios dentro del hook useEffect y no se me actualiza si no llamo al componente.
Alguna solucion?
Este es el codigo, mi idea era actualizar el número de la url, en la consola si que se actualiza la variable pages, pero no me actualiza la url y no me pinta el nuevo contenido. Gracias por su ayuda.

```
const Movies = () => {
  
  const [movies,setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [pages,setpages] = useState(1);
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=9218b9bd6999a8af1b8972bb1b4b815a&language=es-ES&page=${pages}`)
    .then(res => setMovies(res.data.results))
    .catch(console.error);        
  },[]);

  const changeplus = () =>{
    setpages (pages + 1);
    console.log(pages)
  }

  const changeless = () => {
    if (pages > 1) {
     setpages (pages - 1);
    }
  }
  

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Navegador movies/>
      </div>
      <div className="container-movies">
        {movies?.map(movie=><Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie}/>)}
      </div>
      <div className='container-icons'>
        <button
        onClick={changeless}
        ><FaArrowLeft/>
        </button>
        <button
        onClick={changeplus}
        ><FaArrowRight/>
        </button>      
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Movies
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema que tenia es que no actualizaba el axios, esto se realiza en el array final, poniéndole el estado actual de la constante movies.
El resultado es el siguiente.

```
useEffect(()=> {
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=9218b9bd6999a8af1b8972bb1b4b815a&language=es-ES&page=${pages}`)
    .then(res => setMovies(res.data.results))
    .catch(console.error);        
  },[movies]);
```